# ECommerce solution in php and ror

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm a developer but I never used php nor ruby on rails. I would like to create a small e-commerce website.

I found out 2 solutions that seems very good, Prestahop and Spree.

Which one would you recommend if I want to be able to customize the skin, calculate different taxes for different countries, use different languages ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Magento

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is certainly the market leader at the moment.

Their software offers:

The basic products, customers, sales, product categories, tags, reviews and adds some excellet additional features such as being able to control multiple websites, search engine friendly URLs by default, customer newsletters and a huge selection of payment options.

**Other options to consider are:**

- [OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)
- [BigCartel](http://bigcartel.com/)
- [CubeCart](http://www.cubecart.com/)
- [AbleCommerce](http://www.ablecommerce.com/)

Answer (score 1):

for php i would recommend [magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/). It has a big community behind it and has extensive functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a big Magento project and it was a lot of work but well worth it. Magento is very customizable as far as skins and layouts. Prestashop looks nice but a few months ago when I reviewed it I thought the documentation and user community was lacking and most of what I did find was in French. If you want something simple but with a lot of features then take a look at Zencart. The default doesn't look very good but it can be customized.

Answer (score 0):

I would say PrestaShop man, I never heard of Spree, but i take a look at it now, looks interesting.

I build eCommerce shops all the time and built all successful ones and I am using PrestaShop.

I tried Magento, but it was the biggest pain in the ass ever.
It would continuously crash on me and i hated it,

But if you were going with a huge project, like a huge site, 
get a developer and use Magento

PrestaShop you can do it on your own or visit my site and i can help you build a nice small eCommerce site that pulls in a yearly salary

Comment: How do you do authorize.net payment transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Software Droid, I read about it recently on joelonsoftware, it's built just for selling software: http://www.softwaredroid.com/

We've used it on 2 of our sites, it can't do multi languages but it does do multi currency depending on location which is pretty spectacular.